# expected value greater than probability

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I'm supposed to prove that for any Random Variable X,

$E[X^4] \ge \frac 14 P(X^2\ge \frac 12)$

I tried substituting the definitions of expected value and of the probability into the inequality, but that gets me no where.

Any tips on where to go with this proof? Would a moment generating function lead me in the right direction? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality). For a random variable $$X \ge 0, P[X \ge a] \le \frac{E[X]}{a}.$$

We have

\begin{align}
P[X^2 \ge \frac{1}{2}] &= P[X^4 \ge \frac{1}{4}] \qquad \textit{[$X^2 \ge 0$, and $(\cdot)^2$ is a non-decreasing bijective function on $\mathbb{R}_+$]}\\
&\le \frac{E[X^4]}{\frac{1}{4}}.
\end{align}

Re-arranging gives the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
Chebyshev’s Inequality
$P[\arrowvert x \arrowvert \geq a]\leq \frac{E[x^2]}{a^2}$